# 'top' shows 'echo "find"' processes using 100% CPU time

Tags: cpu, process, find, cpu-load, echo

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server, and found that some processes are running with root privileges and takes all my processor time. The processes are called 'echo "find"'. What are these, and how can I stop them?

[image: echo "find" processes]

Comment: Looking at the process tree (parents, grandparents etc.) might shed some light e.g. `pstree -sp 26709`?

Comment: `sudo pkill echo` should find all processes running called echo and kill them, man pkill to check. You can scroll to a process in htop and do F9, then choose the signal to send, the default is SIGKILL I think. These seem weird, could be malware named "echo" doing something on files selected using `find`?? Agree with @steeldriver; perhaps your freshclam is doing this??

Answer (score 2):

You can check its process ID, with `ls -l /proc/1639` 
 and trace its activity with `sudo strace -p 1639`

According to [this](http://forums.openmediavault.org/index.php/Thread/12431-High-CPU-Usage-due-to-process-rqmyjmyswa-echo-find/) thread it's a malware with root permissions.